# How can I tell that a particular planet is under an embargo?

Tags: star-trader-rpg

In several playthroughs now I've managed to accidentally cause a faction to become extremely angry at me for violating their embargo.  However, I can't seem to figure out ahead of time that there is one until after I make the trade.  Is there any way of finding out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played this in a while, but I believe there's a `News` option or something like that. Someone to talk to who will give you information on what's going on in the galaxy. They will sometimes inform you of an embargo on a planet. I've had the same issue, and it's extremely annoying.

Comment: hmm... I wasn't able to find the news button anywhere.

Comment: It may not be exactly news. It's in one of the places you get missions. A pub or bar or something, maybe?

Comment: I finally found it, if you switch the tab from quadrant rumors to faction conflicts (see my answer) you'll be able to see a list of trade embargos.

Answer (score 0):

Hiring a political officer seems to be the only way to know for sure that there is currently an embargo on the planet.  They will warn you when before you attempt to purchase goods from an embargoed planet.

Also, if you go to the rumors tab and click on the white button near the top, you will be taken to the Faction Conflicts tab where you can see a list of all current trade embargos that are going on.

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful. I never was able to figure out what most officers did.